# Grouping different data in one SQL table

Tags: sql, database

I'm writing a GUI application that is essentially a front end to a complicated command-line application. The command takes many separate files as input.

The specification calls for a sqlite database to store links to the file paths as well as 'run sessions' that contain all of the information need to kick off the run as well as some meta data.

There are several different type of input files. Each file could be used in multiple runs.

I was thinking a could store links to all files along with a '`Type`' field in a single table. Something like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE files
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Description TEXT,
Type TEXT,
File TEXT,
Size INTEGER,
Hash TEXT
);
```

The `Type` field would contain give the file type like '`Info`', '`Player`', and '`Picture`'. And then the `sessions` table would have foreign keys that point to the `files` table:

```
CREATE TABLE sessions
(
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
Date TEXT,
User Text,
...
InfoFile INTEGER REFERENCES files (id),
PlayerFile INTEGER REFERENCES files (id),
PictureFile INTEGER REFERENCES files(id),
...
);
```

Is there any downside storing all of the files in a single table, or should I split them into different tables according to file type? (or none of the above?)

Comment: Standard practice. If you wanted to normalize it further you could also create a FileType table to replace the Type text column you have and link the File table to it. The table then describes the different purposes for you. The setup is similar to a lookup table with a PK, a Type FK, a Name, and a Value.

Comment: Actually, normalizing it further would entail creating separate InfoFile, PlayerFile and PictureFile tables. "Type" columns in a relational table are a design smell.

Answer (score 0):

That's the concept of normalization and denormalization.

Normalize database works better for the applications are write-intensive and write-load is more than the read-load, because:
 because:
(1)Normalized tables are smaller because the data is divided vertically among many tables, allow them small enough to get fit into the buffer;
(2)Update and insert are very fast because the data is located at a  single place and no duplicates;
(3)Selects are only fast in cases where data has to be fetched from a single table;
(4)Group by or distinct queries are faster because data is not duplicated.
(5)But joining means read operations have to suffer because indexing strategies do not go well with table joins.

Denormalized database works better for heavy read-load and read-intensive, because:
(1)Data in same table, select are very fast because no need for any joins;
(2)More efficient index usage because table with all the required data.
(3)Updates and inserts become complex and costly,  but because data is duplicated

Comment: In my particular case I don't expect a very intensive read or write load. My main concern isn't so much performance as it making sure I don't create  an architecture that will need to be re-written if the requirements grow. Maybe I'm overthinking it though for a relatively simple problem.

Comment: One big downside to put then into one table is lots of duplicated data, and not easy understand for me. If you want to grab them from one place, you can try to created an indexed views. I prefer to split them to different tables, each table means one entity, File or Session.